# Reading a spritesheet XML file in XNA

Tags: c#, xml, xna, sprite-sheet

Hey i've been looking around for a while now and i still cant find a straight answer to this problem. I have an XNA game in which part of the UI shows an icon which will change every so often(how often is irrelevant). I have decided to use a simple spritesheet maker which outputs the spritesheet as well as a simple XML file with the locations of each of the seperate icons in it.

What i would like to be able to do is read the spritesheet location and icon size of the appropriate icon from the XML file into a `Rectangle`. Then i can just use this as the source rectangle for the drawing bit.

However i have yet to come across a simple explanation of how to load in XML files into an XNA 4.0 project without writing my own content pipeline (something i would like to avoid if possible) and once loaded how to effectively (in general) extract the data into the `Rectangle` variable.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with TexturePacker http://texturepacker.com-->
<!-- $TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:748fc56befb00c22540f953093f731a7$ -->
<!--Format:
n  => name of the sprite
x  => sprite x pos in texture
y  => sprite y pos in texture
w  => sprite width (may be trimmed)
h  => sprite height (may be trimmed)
oX => sprite's x-corner offset (only available if trimmed)
oY => sprite's y-corner offset (only available if trimmed)
oW => sprite's original width (only available if trimmed)
oH => sprite's original height (only available if trimmed)
r => 'y' only set if sprite is rotated
-->
<TextureAtlas imagePath="Loadout_Icons.png" width="185" height="86">
    <sprite n="Charge_Down.png" x="0" y="0" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="Charge_Up.png" x="37" y="0" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="Damage_Down.png" x="74" y="0" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="Damage_Up.png" x="111" y="0" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="FireRate_Down.png" x="148" y="0" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="FireRate_Up.png" x="0" y="43" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="Health_Down.png" x="37" y="43" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="Health_Up.png" x="74" y="43" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="Speed_Down.png" x="111" y="43" w="37" h="43"/>
    <sprite n="Speed_Up.png" x="148" y="43" w="37" h="43"/>
</TextureAtlas>
```

Also im not sure if im shooting myself in the foot by not making my own XML files, would that be easier?

I have read most of what msdn had to offer with no avail but any links to relevant pages or questions would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking to avoid the content pipeline, why is that? You wish to load it at runtime manually instead?

Comment: @William'MindWorX'Mariager I dont want to avoid the pipeline entirely however a couple of the tutorials i have read involve expanding upon it in a rather complex way which i have not been able to understand. If there was a built-in way or a simple way of doing then that would be optimal.

Comment: While I certainly approve of implementing the content pipeline importer and processor yourself for learning reasons, someone else already did it: http://thirdpartyninjas.com/blog/2012/08/02/texturepacker-xna-content-pipeline-extension/

Comment: @NikoDrašković Thanks for the link, was very helpful and i have decided to use their extensions to solve my initial problem. Just a pitty i couldn't find a more general solution for anyone else in this situation who isnt using texture packer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was only mentioned in a comment I decided to say that I ended up using Niko Drašković's suggestion of the purpose built pipeline extension made specifically for texture packer which can be found at http://thirdpartyninjas.com/blog/2012/08/02/texturepacker-xna-content-pipeline-extension/. That make it very easy to work with XML files produced by texture packer.

However as a bit of a side note and another reason why I revisited this question was to say that I have been doing a fair bit of work with XML's lately (trying to get a better understanding for them) and the best way that I have found to deal with reading custom XML files without writing a new pipeline extension for each one (as elegant as that now seems)is as follows. I add the XML file to the content directory like you would any other texture etc. In the properties of the XML I set *Build Action* to "Content" and then *Copy to Output Directory* to "Copy Always". From here I have a separate class in which I pass in the name of the file and inside which I process everything I need from the XML. These classes start with:

```
Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Content\\" + fileName + ".xml");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

and then go on (using the rest of the System.Xml.Linq library) to read and store the appropriate data, with methods to access data easily. This may **not** be the best approach to tackling the problem but it has since worked for me and is simple enough to understand and implement quickly. Hope this can help anyone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, however, it's entirely untested:

```
[XmlRoot("TextureAtlas", IsNullable = false)]
public class TextureAtlasXml
{
    public static TextureAtlasXml FromFile(String file)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            return FromStream(stream);
        }
    }

    public static TextureAtlasXml FromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TextureAtlasXml));
        return (TextureAtlasXml)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }


    [XmlAttribute("imagePath")]
    public String ImagePath;

    [XmlAttribute("width")]
    public Int32 Width;

    [XmlAttribute("height")]
    public Int32 Height;

    [XmlElement("sprite")]
    public List<SpriteXml> Sprites;
}

public class SpriteXml
{
    [XmlAttribute("n")]
    public String Name;

    [XmlAttribute("x")]
    public Int32 X;

    [XmlAttribute("y")]
    public Int32 Y;

    [XmlAttribute("w")]
    public Int32 Width;

    [XmlAttribute("h")]
    public Int32 Height;

    public Rectangle Rectangle { get { return new Rectangle(this.X, this.Y, this.Width, this.Height); } }
}
```

I would recommend you look into using the content pipeline, as it gives a nice solution, however, the code should work like you want.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the effort you took to answer the question, is there a way you could give a link to a 'nice solution' so i could compare the two ways. Ultimately if using part of the content pipeline is simpler and easier to understand i would be inclined to go with that. Thanks again!

Comment: @WillBagley, That'll take a bit more time. I'll see if I can get around to doing it when I get home. But basically, you need to create a ContentImporter and a ContentProcessor. The nice thing is, you just load your spritesheet, and it'll also automatically load up the Texture2Ds necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use Sprite Vortex (a specific version actually) you can use the following class. 
You have to use Sprite Vortex 1.2.2 because in the newer versions the XML format is changed. Make sure that the XML file you add the property is changed to "Do not compile".

If you need a working example I can send you a very simple one.

p.s. Sprite Vortex should do the same thing you use the other program for, however v 1.2.2 is pretty buggy but not too bad.

the class is here :  http://pastebin.com/sNSa7xgQ